# Auth Session Servlet java jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I always go to `ELSE` statement in my code below:

```
if (session == null) {

            request.setAttribute("stts_log", "Login");
            request.setAttribute("btn_modal", "exambutton");
            request.setAttribute("btn_href", "#");
            out.print("Please login first");  
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index2.jsp");  
            rd.forward(request, response); 

        } else {
            request.setAttribute("sess", session);
            request.setAttribute("stts_log", "Logout");
            request.setAttribute("btn_modal", "");
            request.setAttribute("btn_href", "ControllerServlet");
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index2.jsp");  
            rd.forward(request, response); 
        }
```

Comment: Then the session is probably not null; how are you getting that? Please post a MCVE.

Comment: but I have never create session..its just index page